# Sort command ignores the first row

Tags: sql-server, linux, sorting, gnu, byte-order-mark

I'm having this problem with the sort where it is ignoring the first line. file1 is a bunch of data with the first column separated by a tab (\t)

My command:

> sort -n file1 > file2

My file2:

> 10000356869   Music                      ,5330548481       ,Maroon 5
>   99858 Apps / Software / Website  ,586481691394593  ,Best Vines
>   99859 Community                  ,427045773976651  ,Friends of the Blu
>   99860 Company                    ,83564764229      ,MAPCO
>   99861 Company                    ,90301409621      ,Charter Communicat

I believe that this is because the file was imported from a windows environment. It is the result of a MSSQL query. I was wondering if this is beacuse there is no '^' start of line character on the first line, or that it is not preceded by a '$' end of line. Could that be the cause? what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to take out any leading tabs and spaces before you run the sort command. Try this:

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sort -n file1 > file2
```

Comment: I think you mean "sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' file1 | sort -n > file2". And that didn't work. There are no trailing tabs or spaces in the data file. It seems that the sort option is starting from the second line.

Comment: I'm finding out that this has to do with the way MSSQL data files are saved in windows. That file1.csv file ends a data file with 'CRLF' files created in vi have the default 'LF' but no 'CR'.  But I can't figure out how to fix this.